# Ext Form with fileuploadfield (response after submit)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extjs

Can`t really understand where is a mistake..

I have a form with fileuploadfield. Request is sended good, action on my controller gets all params, works with them, and sends response to browser. But in html page, after submiting the form, always fires FAILURE event, and never SUCCESS.

Client Side Code

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        renderTo: 'Container',
        bodyPadding: '10 10 0',
        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'form',
            width: 300,
            border: false,
            fileUpload: true,
            items: [
            {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                id: 'PayTypes',
                width: 215,
                store: PayTypesStore,
                valueField: 'id',
                displayField: 'Name',
                editable: false,
                name: 'id'
            }
            ,
            {
                xtype: 'filefield',
                id: 'form-file',
                name: 'file',
                buttonText: '',
                buttonConfig: {
                    iconCls: 'upload-icon'
                }
            }
            ],
            buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Send',
                handler: function () {
                    var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                    if (form.isValid()) {
                        form.submit({
                            url: 'UploadFile',
                            waitMsg: 'Uploading your photo...',
                            success: function (fp, o) {
                                console.log("success");
                                msg('Success', 'Processed file on the server');
                            },
                            failure: function (form, action) {
                                console.log(action);
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', action.result ? action.result.message : 'No response');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    });
```

Server Side Code:

```
public JsonResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileWrapper file, int id)
    {
        var response = Json(new { success = true });
        response.ContentType = "text/html";

        return Json(response);
    }
```

Response, recieved on the client side:

```
{"ContentEncoding":null,"ContentType":"text/html","Data":"success":true},"JsonRequestBehavior":1,"MaxJsonLength":null,"RecursionLimit":null}
```

What i need to fix in my code to get SUCCESS event after sumniting form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called `Json` method twice. The only thing you need is

```
public JsonResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileWrapper file, int id)
{
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexey!)) Your help was very useful)